# Google Maps API V3: Manually change a circles center when draggable is enabled

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

When I set the center of a "draggable" circle it sometimes gives an error but still changes the center of the circle. There is no error if the circle is not "draggable".

(The error only exists in **chrome** as far as I tested)

Error:

```
js:93 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of null(…)
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mrdpcngf/3/)

Steps to reproduce error: 
 1. Check the "Make draggable" checkbox 
 2. Click on the map to move the circle 
 3. Repeat step 2 multiple times till the error occurred

So my question is: How to not get an error when changing the circles center when it is draggable? or Is there another way to what I want to do?

EDIT: Video on how to reproduce the error: https://youtu.be/j86aV8dqfuk
as some people think there is no error.

Comment: Unable to replicate the error in firefox and chrome. The jsfiddle is running without an error

Comment: Added a video on how to reproduce the error. It might be more clear now on how  to reproduce it.

Comment: I *did* see the error happening in Chrome, but I couldn't work out the steps to make it always happen.

Comment: possible of being a bug?